# Angular - Add a sidebar to a dashboard parent module

Tags: angular, architecture, structure, nav, dashboard

I built a dashboard parent module which contains 2 submodules : usersModule and statsModule

I would like to display a sidebar inside the parent module to navigate accross submodules but I want to avoid calling the sidebar in every module. What is the best way to do that ?

[image: structure]

here is what i got so far

```
# dashboardModule
    statsModule
        containers
        components
    usersModule
        containers
        components
    sharedModule
        services
        guards
        pipes
// other stuff
# homeModule
# eventsModule
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I personally used the Material2 sidenav in my Angular2 project for this purpose, worked great.

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

** guess I should expand**
I used it as a "wrapper" div in my parent component that called all my child components from within that wrapper.

so in my case I had a "sidenav" component that was my parent and all other child components were called/rendered within that view.

**code example**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <Component-selector></Component-selector>
  //or you can place your router outlet here if your using a router
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**here is image of how I structure my project.**
[image]

Comment: hum thanks but its all about architecture, i would like to know how to structure my module to show this navbar across all submodules

Comment: do you have a github link or? because i don't understand how you could put a module inside a component

Comment: see revised code example. Well i refer to all of my Angular 2 items as a component... this may be a miscommunication on my part of using the wrong terms. see code example above, hoping that illustrates further how I did this.

Comment: Here is a link with more information on modules and using the router with them that may help as well.
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-modules

Comment: my structure looks like this https://github.com/UltimateAngular/angular-pro-app-seed/tree/20-schedule-controls/src/health so i could not add a shared navbar here ?

Comment: does that example have a shared nav? or am I miss reading the code? look at the template in https://github.com/UltimateAngular/angular-pro-app-seed/blob/20-schedule-controls/src/app/containers/app/app.component.ts it has almost the same structure I am referring to.

Comment: yes but that "app-nav/app-header" stuff is shared across all the app, i would like an other nav "sidenav" which is only shared across all submodules of the dashbord module. I think i'll do it this way and only display the sidenav if the router url is /dashbord/xxx but thanks anyway

Comment: I am a little confused as to why this is not applicable to your situation... Very possible I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do, sorry if I am. You would just take the same example you provided and use it at the dashboard module level if you only wanted to show the sidenav at that specific level of your application. No worries, hope something in here was helpful and wasn't a complete waste of time. Good luck on your project.